# How to change a input text to textarea in X-editable

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I use a bootstrap table on MVC and one column is editable, but the field for capture the new value is a input text field and I need a textarea

In the code of bootstrap table only I have this (data-editable="true"):

```
<th data-field="Comments" data-editable="true" data-sortable="true" >Comments</th>
```

And in Javascript only I save old value, new value etc..
This is the code:

```
$(document).on('editable-save.bs.table', '#datatable-GeneralTable', function (e, field, row, old, $el) {

       var oldvalue= old;
       var newvalue= row[field];
       var partnumber = row["Part_Number"];

       saveComments(oldvalue,newvalue,partnumber );
});
```

How I can change the input text for a input textarea ??

Answer (score 1):

```
<th data-field="Comments" data-editable="true" data-type="textarea" data-sortable="true" >Comments</th>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the value of text filed using below code. 
$('#elementId.changeDays').editable('option', 'value', obj.days);